# Add a dynamic listview to a fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

In my app I need the possibility to create a dynamic listview populated by elements extracted from the db.

This in itself wouldn't be a big problem (there are a lot of tutorials about it, like [this one](http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/09/dynamic-list-view-demo-in-android.html)), problem is, my activity is divided in tabs and, therefore, I have a `Fragment` for each tab (the code it's basically [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/)).

There are lots of methods that I can't use in a `Fragment`and I'm honestly pretty stuck.

How can I implement a dynamic layout solution inside a fragment?

Edit: code for clarity:

Fragment:

```
package it.sii.mywaiter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class AllerFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.aller_layout, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Activity:

```
package it.sii.mywaiter;

import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
//import android.widget.*;
import android.app.ActionBar;

public class UserPrefActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private PrefPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "Ingredienti preferiti", "Allergie e Intolleranze" };
    int tabsnum = tabs.length;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.user_pref_layout);

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new PrefPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mAdapter.setCount(tabsnum);

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }


}
```

Adapter

```
package it.sii.mywaiter;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class PrefPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private int count = 0;

    public PrefPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public void setCount(int count){
        this.count = count;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            return new PrefFragment();
        case 1:
            return new AllerFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

}
```

Fragment's layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#fa6a6a" >

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="test test"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: place a listview in your fragment's layout and inflate it in your oncreateview method its very basic and similar to activity and all your code like view pager and etc will work.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you have Fragments. Every Fragment has its own class so you can create a CustomArrayAdapter and the use it in the Fragments `onCreate` Method. Inside the Fragment get your ListView, which you defined in the xml File for this Fragment, with `findViewByID` and then set its Adapter with `setAdapter(new YourCustomAdapterClass());` then you have your custom dynamic ListView in a Fragment.